# MSMQ Failed to create an Queue

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

Im trying to pull messages from a queue of the MSMQ service. It works great in one service but in the other it fails to create a queue if it not exists. the line that fails is:

```
_cursor = _queue.CreateCursor();
```

Where CreateCursor is a method of the MessageQueue class.
The exception is:

> Message Queue service is not available

If you need more information let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have appropriate permissions to create a Queue?

Comment: How can I check this in my solution?

Comment: Dumb question, but it has to be asked - is the MQ service running on that machine?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I ran the service in debug mode. When I compiled it and ran in Release mode the problem solved. It seems that queues' creation permission depends on the compilation type of the solution.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. you could not be more wrong here. The queue knows nothing about the build mode - why should it care? This has to do with the user account you are using to create the queue. To access and create queues - this entirely depends on the account permissions your application is running under. Nothing else. Heck, I can create a queue in debug mode no problem right now.